# htaccess RewriteCond always false

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is an easy one, but it's driving my nuts. I'm having trouble with a RewriteCond always evaluating to false. Some facts of the case:

1: My system is Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS). 
2: I have proxy_module  proxy_http_module installed and rewrite_module installed.
3: my public html folder is at var/www/html. No symlinks or aliases.

Alright so the deal is that I have this link:

```
http://mycoolsite.com/fake/
```

And I just want to redirect it to

```
http://mycoolsite.com/real/
```

This rule works perfectly fine:

```
RewriteRule ^fake/(.*)$ http://mycoolsite.com/real/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Sends all the traffic from one folder to the other. However, if I have this RewriteCond in front of that rule:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/fake/$
RewriteRule ^fake/(.*)$ http://mycoolsite.com/real/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then this url:

```
http://mycoolsite.com/fake/
```

just takes me over to the fake directory and that's the end of it. The RewriteRule is ignored. I've logged the server variables with PHP and I see very clearly: 'REQUEST_URI' => '/fake/'. So that url should just be passing through right on to the RewriteRule. So why is my RewriteCond stopping the flow? I know there's something absurdly simple I'm missing here. Here's the full listing of the htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/fake/$
RewriteRule ^fake/(.*)$ http://glowingbluecore.com/real/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(To preempt a question- This example is just to illustrate the trouble that I'm having with RewriteCond. I'm not trying to redirect traffic from one folder to the other.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your misspelled the variable name. It is `% {REQUEST_URI}` not `${REQUEST_URI}` and that is why your Condition is failing.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fake/$
```